# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenInput is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput

I follow

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields
```

and done each and every thing according to this but when it gives me that error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenInput is not a function

(anonymous function) @ products.js?body=1:36jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ application.js?
body=1:3149jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ application.js?body=1:3261jQuery.extend.ready 
@ application.js?body=1:3473completed @ application.js?body=1:3504
```

My jquery code is

```
$(function() {

 $("#textarea1").tokenInput("/products.json", {

 crossDomain: false,

 theme: "facebook"

 });

});
```

> Rails version is Rails 4.2.4 and ruby version is ruby 2.2.1

Comment: Please show the complete error message and the relevant code parts.

Comment: Please assume with your questions that other people don't want to go and watch a whole railscast to understand your problem:  your problem should be presented as a completely standalone question, ie "here's my code: here's the error:  what's the problem?"